# How do you write the update function for a*sinx where a is the slider value and the amplitude

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter-canvas

I am very new to matplotlib dynamic visualizations and GUIs. So, could you help me out how to write the update function since the graph I'm getting is definitely not a sine graph. This code is what I've written after seeing many similar codes and videos. lemme know where I went wrong. thanks.
\\\

```
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Sine graph")
fig = plt.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand =1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.25)
y_values = []
x_values = [random.randrange(-10,11) for _ in range(10)]
for i in range(len(x_values)):
    y_values.append(np.sin(2*np.pi*x_values[i]))
ax.axis([(-np.pi-2), (np.pi+2), -10, 10])
ax_value = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])
s_time = Slider(ax_value, 'Value', 0, 30, valinit=0)
(l,) = ax.plot(x_values, y_values)
def update(val):
    pos = s_time.val
    l.set_ydata(pos*np.sin(l.get_xdata()))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
s_time.on_changed(update)
tk.mainloop()
```

\\\

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. Maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: are you sure it has to be `pos*np.sin(l.get_xdata())` ? Maybe `pos*np.sin(2*np.pi*l.get_xdata())` or `pos*y_values`?

Comment: are you sure you want `x_values` in random order? it generate something like `[2, -2, -8, -5, -8, -7, 6, -5, -5, 9]` but maybe you should rather has `x_values = range(10)` to get `[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and later use random values to generate `y_values`. OR maybe you should sort `x_values` before use to generate `y_values`

Comment: other problem can be that `y_values` can be very small but you use y axis `-10, 10`

Comment: maybe you should add in question (not in comments) links to similar codes and videos. As for me update work correctly but you simply have  wrong values in `x_values`, `y_values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me all problem is that you use wrong values in `x_values` and `y_values`

`x_values` should be values in range `-10, 10`
`y_values` should be values `sin(x_values)` - it doesn't need to convert `2*PI`

You could also use numpy.array to generate values so later you don't have to use `for`-loop

```
x_values = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y_values = np.sin(x_values)
```

And in update you should also use `y_values` instead of `l.get_xdata()` and calculate again `sin()`

BTW: you can use `val` instead of `s_time.val`

```
def update(val):
    new_y_values = val*y_values
    line.set_ydata(new_y_values)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

I would also changed `axis`. `x_values` are in range `-10, 10` and `y_values` are in range `-1, 1` and `slider` can has value `0 30` so `pos*y_values` can be in range `-30, 30`

```
ax.axis([-10, 10, -30, 30])
```

eventually I would add margin at top and bottom

```
ax.axis([-10, 10, -31, 31])
```

---

Full working code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

# --- functions ---
def update(val):
    new_y_values = val*y_values
    line.set_ydata(new_y_values)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# --- main ---

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Sine graph")

fig = plt.Figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand =True)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.25)

x_values = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y_values = np.sin(x_values)

print(x_values)
print(y_values)

(line,) = ax.plot(x_values, y_values)

ax.axis([-10, 10, -31, 31])
ax_value = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.78, 0.03])

s_time = Slider(ax_value, 'Value', 0, 30, valinit=1)
s_time.on_changed(update)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the other tips, now I have a better understanding of how the code works.